# Does tag manager have a built in way to grab the user's browser (i.e. chrome) and OS ? (for the web)

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Does tag manager have a way to grab the user's browser version and os?
I know that it can do this in apps through the pre-defined 'device' variables. But i was wondering if it has something similar for the web built in?

OR

will i simply have to roll out my own solution in JS that pushes the browser version and OS to the datalayer, where it can be grabbed by a custom event tag?


Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such a function in Google Tag Manager. If you need this functionality, there is a few approaches.

First, ask yourself, how precise information you need. If you need high granularity, try some detecting scripts like:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ChristianL/AVyND/ 

/**
 * JavaScript Client Detection
 * (C) viazenetti GmbH (Christian Ludwig)
 */
(function (window) {
    {
        var unknown = '-';

        // screen
        var screenSize = '';
        if (screen.width) {
            width = (screen.width) ? screen.width : '';
            height = (screen.height) ? screen.height : '';
            screenSize += '' + width + " x " + height;
        }

        //browser
        var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
        var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
        var browser = navigator.appName;
        var version = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
        var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
        var nameOffset, verOffset, ix;

        // Opera
        if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Opera')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Opera';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 6);
            if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {
                version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
            }
        }
        // MSIE
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('MSIE')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 5);
        }
        // Chrome
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Chrome')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Chrome';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
        }
        // Safari
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Safari')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Safari';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
            if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {
                version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
            }
        }
        // Firefox
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Firefox')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Firefox';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
        }
        // MSIE 11+
        else if (nAgt.indexOf('Trident/') != -1) {
            browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';
            version = nAgt.substring(nAgt.indexOf('rv:') + 3);
        }
        // Other browsers
        else if ((nameOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1) < (verOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf('/'))) {
            browser = nAgt.substring(nameOffset, verOffset);
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 1);
            if (browser.toLowerCase() == browser.toUpperCase()) {
                browser = navigator.appName;
            }
        }
        // trim the version string
        if ((ix = version.indexOf(';')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
        if ((ix = version.indexOf(' ')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
        if ((ix = version.indexOf(')')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);

        majorVersion = parseInt('' + version, 10);
        if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
            version = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
            majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
        }

        // mobile version
        var mobile = /Mobile|mini|Fennec|Android|iP(ad|od|hone)/.test(nVer);

        // cookie
        var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

        if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == 'undefined' && !cookieEnabled) {
            document.cookie = 'testcookie';
            cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf('testcookie') != -1) ? true : false;
        }

        // system
        var os = unknown;
        var clientStrings = [
            {s:'Windows 10', r:/(Windows 10.0|Windows NT 10.0)/},
            {s:'Windows 8.1', r:/(Windows 8.1|Windows NT 6.3)/},
            {s:'Windows 8', r:/(Windows 8|Windows NT 6.2)/},
            {s:'Windows 7', r:/(Windows 7|Windows NT 6.1)/},
            {s:'Windows Vista', r:/Windows NT 6.0/},
            {s:'Windows Server 2003', r:/Windows NT 5.2/},
            {s:'Windows XP', r:/(Windows NT 5.1|Windows XP)/},
            {s:'Windows 2000', r:/(Windows NT 5.0|Windows 2000)/},
            {s:'Windows ME', r:/(Win 9x 4.90|Windows ME)/},
            {s:'Windows 98', r:/(Windows 98|Win98)/},
            {s:'Windows 95', r:/(Windows 95|Win95|Windows_95)/},
            {s:'Windows NT 4.0', r:/(Windows NT 4.0|WinNT4.0|WinNT|Windows NT)/},
            {s:'Windows CE', r:/Windows CE/},
            {s:'Windows 3.11', r:/Win16/},
            {s:'Android', r:/Android/},
            {s:'Open BSD', r:/OpenBSD/},
            {s:'Sun OS', r:/SunOS/},
            {s:'Linux', r:/(Linux|X11)/},
            {s:'iOS', r:/(iPhone|iPad|iPod)/},
            {s:'Mac OS X', r:/Mac OS X/},
            {s:'Mac OS', r:/(MacPPC|MacIntel|Mac_PowerPC|Macintosh)/},
            {s:'QNX', r:/QNX/},
            {s:'UNIX', r:/UNIX/},
            {s:'BeOS', r:/BeOS/},
            {s:'OS/2', r:/OS\/2/},
            {s:'Search Bot', r:/(nuhk|Googlebot|Yammybot|Openbot|Slurp|MSNBot|Ask Jeeves\/Teoma|ia_archiver)/}
        ];
        for (var id in clientStrings) {
            var cs = clientStrings[id];
            if (cs.r.test(nAgt)) {
                os = cs.s;
                break;
            }
        }

        var osVersion = unknown;

        if (/Windows/.test(os)) {
            osVersion = /Windows (.*)/.exec(os)[1];
            os = 'Windows';
        }

        switch (os) {
            case 'Mac OS X':
                osVersion = /Mac OS X (10[\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
                break;

            case 'Android':
                osVersion = /Android ([\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
                break;

            case 'iOS':
                osVersion = /OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/.exec(nVer);
                osVersion = osVersion[1] + '.' + osVersion[2] + '.' + (osVersion[3] | 0);
                break;
        }

        // flash (you'll need to include swfobject)
        /* script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js" */
        var flashVersion = 'no check';
        if (typeof swfobject != 'undefined') {
            var fv = swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion();
            if (fv.major > 0) {
                flashVersion = fv.major + '.' + fv.minor + ' r' + fv.release;
            }
            else  {
                flashVersion = unknown;
            }
        }
    }

    window.jscd = {
        screen: screenSize,
        browser: browser,
        browserVersion: version,
        mobile: mobile,
        os: os,
        osVersion: osVersion,
        cookies: cookieEnabled,
        flashVersion: flashVersion
    };
}(this));

alert(
    'OS: ' + jscd.os +' '+ jscd.osVersion + '\n'+
    'Browser: ' + jscd.browser +' '+ jscd.browserVersion + '\n' + 
    'Mobile: ' + jscd.mobile + '\n' +
    'Flash: ' + jscd.flashVersion + '\n' +
    'Cookies: ' + jscd.cookies + '\n' +
    'Screen Size: ' + jscd.screen + '\n\n' +
    'Full User Agent: ' + navigator.userAgent
);
```

and for you purpose, modify it a little like this:

```
(function (window) {
    {
        var unknown = '-';

        //browser
        var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
        var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
        var browser = navigator.appName;
        var version = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
        var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
        var nameOffset, verOffset, ix;

        // Opera
        if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Opera')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Opera';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 6);
            if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {
                version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
            }
        }
        // MSIE
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('MSIE')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 5);
        }
        // Chrome
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Chrome')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Chrome';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
        }
        // Safari
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Safari')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Safari';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
            if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {
                version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
            }
        }
        // Firefox
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Firefox')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Firefox';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
        }
        // MSIE 11+
        else if (nAgt.indexOf('Trident/') != -1) {
            browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';
            version = nAgt.substring(nAgt.indexOf('rv:') + 3);
        }
        // Other browsers
        else if ((nameOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1) < (verOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf('/'))) {
            browser = nAgt.substring(nameOffset, verOffset);
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 1);
            if (browser.toLowerCase() == browser.toUpperCase()) {
                browser = navigator.appName;
            }
        }
        // trim the version string
        if ((ix = version.indexOf(';')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
        if ((ix = version.indexOf(' ')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
        if ((ix = version.indexOf(')')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);

        majorVersion = parseInt('' + version, 10);
        if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
            version = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
            majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
        }

        // system
        var os = unknown;
        var clientStrings = [
            {s:'Windows 10', r:/(Windows 10.0|Windows NT 10.0)/},
            {s:'Windows 8.1', r:/(Windows 8.1|Windows NT 6.3)/},
            {s:'Windows 8', r:/(Windows 8|Windows NT 6.2)/},
            {s:'Windows 7', r:/(Windows 7|Windows NT 6.1)/},
            {s:'Windows Vista', r:/Windows NT 6.0/},
            {s:'Windows Server 2003', r:/Windows NT 5.2/},
            {s:'Windows XP', r:/(Windows NT 5.1|Windows XP)/},
            {s:'Windows 2000', r:/(Windows NT 5.0|Windows 2000)/},
            {s:'Windows ME', r:/(Win 9x 4.90|Windows ME)/},
            {s:'Windows 98', r:/(Windows 98|Win98)/},
            {s:'Windows 95', r:/(Windows 95|Win95|Windows_95)/},
            {s:'Windows NT 4.0', r:/(Windows NT 4.0|WinNT4.0|WinNT|Windows NT)/},
            {s:'Windows CE', r:/Windows CE/},
            {s:'Windows 3.11', r:/Win16/},
            {s:'Android', r:/Android/},
            {s:'Open BSD', r:/OpenBSD/},
            {s:'Sun OS', r:/SunOS/},
            {s:'Linux', r:/(Linux|X11)/},
            {s:'iOS', r:/(iPhone|iPad|iPod)/},
            {s:'Mac OS X', r:/Mac OS X/},
            {s:'Mac OS', r:/(MacPPC|MacIntel|Mac_PowerPC|Macintosh)/},
            {s:'QNX', r:/QNX/},
            {s:'UNIX', r:/UNIX/},
            {s:'BeOS', r:/BeOS/},
            {s:'OS/2', r:/OS\/2/},
            {s:'Search Bot', r:/(nuhk|Googlebot|Yammybot|Openbot|Slurp|MSNBot|Ask Jeeves\/Teoma|ia_archiver)/}
        ];
        for (var id in clientStrings) {
            var cs = clientStrings[id];
            if (cs.r.test(nAgt)) {
                os = cs.s;
                break;
            }
        }

        var osVersion = unknown;

        if (/Windows/.test(os)) {
            osVersion = /Windows (.*)/.exec(os)[1];
            os = 'Windows';
        }

        switch (os) {
            case 'Mac OS X':
                osVersion = /Mac OS X (10[\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
                break;

            case 'Android':
                osVersion = /Android ([\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
                break;

            case 'iOS':
                osVersion = /OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/.exec(nVer);
                osVersion = osVersion[1] + '.' + osVersion[2] + '.' + (osVersion[3] | 0);
                break;
        }       

    }

    window.jscd = {

        browser: browser,
        browserVersion: version,      
        os: os,
        osVersion: osVersion,

    };
}(this));

alert(
    'OS: ' + jscd.os +' '+ jscd.osVersion + '\n'+
    'Browser: ' + jscd.browser +' '+ jscd.browserVersion 
);
```

### GTM implementation

1) create new TAG type Custom Javascript/HTML containing this script (or any different with same purpose) and this script will create window scoped object jscd with all data like OS, OS version, Browser, etc... | Firing rule should be URL = Regex = .*

2) create new macros/variables for each information you need. Type Javascript variable and you type: jscd.browser; jscd.browserVersion; jscd.os; jscd.osVersion

---

Now you can use this information everywhere in your GTM container

Comment: just the information i was looking for, I suspected i might have to use navigator. to manually figure out what device, OS etc the user is on. Thanks a lot for the help.